# Constant Volume vs. Constant Pressure?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, thermodynamics

Approaching the following question:

> Consider two experiments in which 2 moles of a monatomic ideal gas are
>   heated from temperature $T$ to temperature $T + \Delta T$: in the
>   first experiment the volume $V$ is kept constant, in the second
>   experiment the pressure $p$ is kept constant. How much more heat is
>   needed in the second experiment than in the first experiment to raise
>   the temperature by the given amount $\Delta T$?

The answer is $2 R \Delta T$.

The origin of the problem may be found [here](http://online.physics.uiuc.edu/cgi/courses/shell/phys213/practice.pl?exam1/su11) under *Question 14*.

I am confused as to home to come to this conclusion.  I believe I am able to utilize $pV = N k_B T$ and $VT^\alpha = const$, $pV^\gamma = const$ but I am unsure of how the two constants apply to this.

Do both constant apply to each of the experiments?  How do I manipulate these equations to achieve my desired result?

Comment: $pV^\gamma=\text{const.}$ and $VT^\alpha=\text{const.}$ are both equations for adiabatic process, not isobaric or isochoric.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the first experiment, work done is 0 as volume is constant. Using the first law of thermodynamics $q=U-w$, $q=\Delta U$. In the second case extra heat is needed due to the work done which is $\Delta(pV)=p\Delta V$, as pressure is constant. Using the ideal gas equation $p \Delta V = nR \Delta T=2R\Delta T$. Note the change in internal energy depends only on the change in temperature and is same in both the cases.

Comment: @ramunujan A nice explanation and probably at a more appropriate level than mine. I would point out, though, that for homework-tagged questions, the preference is to help the OP answer the question themselves, rather than work out/give them the answer.

Answer (score 1):

To avoid giving the answer but to steer you down the right path, consider the heat capacity for an ideal gas at constant pressure vs. constant volume: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ideal_gas#Heat_capacity

Comment: this should be a comment.